# VB.Net Encryption Function to PHP

Tags: php, vb.net, encryption

Ok so i've been learning a couple of weeks about encryption, a friend of mine have an encryption function in VB.Net and he gave it to me so i can transfered it to PHP for some test.

the decryptions works 50% of the times.
Sometimes i get an accurate result and the other i just get some encrypted stuff.
I dont know where i am wrong, i've been playing with these codes the last 2 weeks and i getting me mad.

VB.NET Code

```
#Region "Llaves"
Private patron_busqueda As String = "3AnB12CDEopFIJKÑcdOP0QRSTU56VWXYZabe9fLMNghi7jklmñqrstuvwx4yz8GH"
Private Patron_encripta As String = "B0CDdE3GHIst8JKL6MNPQR2STUVWX7YZabcÑ5OefghijklFmnñ4opqruv1wxyz9A"
#End Region
Public Function DesEncriptarCadena(ByVal cadena As String) As String
    Dim idx As Integer
    Dim result As String = ""

    For idx = 0 To cadena.Length - 1
        result += DesEncriptarCaracter(cadena.Substring(idx, 1), cadena.Length, idx)
    Next
    Return result
End Function
Private Function DesEncriptarCaracter(ByVal caracter As String, _
                 ByVal variable As Integer, ByVal a_indice As Integer) As String
    Dim indice As Integer

    If Patron_encripta.IndexOf(caracter) <> -1 Then
        If (Patron_encripta.IndexOf(caracter) - variable - a_indice) > 0 Then
            indice = (Patron_encripta.IndexOf(caracter) - variable - a_indice) Mod Patron_encripta.Length
        Else
            'La línea está cortada por falta de espacio
            indice = (patron_busqueda.Length) + ((Patron_encripta.IndexOf(caracter) - variable - a_indice) Mod Patron_encripta.Length)
        End If
        indice = indice Mod Patron_encripta.Length
        Return patron_busqueda.Substring(indice, 1)
    Else
        Return caracter
    End If
End Function
```

PHP Code

```
$patron_busqueda = "3AnB12CDEopFIJKNcdOP0QRSTU56VWXYZabe9fLMNghi7jklmnqrstuvwx4yz8GH";
$pb=str_split($patron_busqueda,1);
$pblargo=strlen($patron_busqueda);
$patron_encripta = "B0CDdE3GHIst8JKL6MNPQR2STUVWX7YZabcN5OefghijklFmnn4opqruv1wxyz9A";
$pe=str_split($patron_encripta,1);
$pelargo=strlen($patron_encripta);
$i=0;
$encrypted=str_split($res,1);
$decrypted="";
$res="5555444433332222"
  $largo=strlen($res);
while ( $i < $largo) {
    $x = array_search($encrypted[$i], $pe);
    $x = $x-$largo-$i;
   if ($x>=0) {
            $z = $pb[$x];
            $decrypted=$decrypted.$z;
            $i=$i+1;
    }else{
    $x = $pblargo+($x);
    $z = $pb[$x];
    $decrypted=$decrypted.$z;
    $i=$i+1;
    }
 }
```

Any guide/help would be much appreciated

Comment: Is this an academic exercise or are you porting this for some application purpose?

Comment: If this is supposed to be a direct port, then why are you splitting your "scramblers" to arrays?

Comment: Whenever you translate between two languages, try to make as literal as possible translations, even if they are dumb or not optimal or there's a built-in way to do it. Once that works, then you can start to optimize.

Comment: I rolled back your edit to your question because you posted the answer in there. You can post an answer to your own question.